# SQL Select ID from automatically generated rows with C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Basically whenever i would press a button on my website it would generate some kind of report with the ID and other information. What am trying to do is change one column of the table with SQL statements. I managed to change it but the code changes the column for all the IDs. What am trying to do is change column according to ID, but am still new to C# and SQL so i'm not sure how to get the automatic generated row. Just to highlight that i'm using a button in a gridview to change the value in the column. Below is what i tried:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        string order = Request.QueryString["id"];

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RCManiaConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();

        if (e.CommandName == "received")
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "UPDATE [Orders] SET Status = 'Received' WHERE [ID] ='" + order + "'";
            SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the code changes the column for all IDs"?  Is it just in the grid or are all records in the database also being updated?  As an aside, you should definitely look into using parameterized SQL as this code is basically a textbook risk of SQL injection.

Comment: No it changes the column that i want but for all entries. So i need a way to change the column according to the ID. This is just for personal use

Comment: Two things, first try to confirm that the SQL being generated is what you expect.  I could not see how the SQL would update all records in the database unless they all had the same `[ID]` field.  Second, you don't need `ExecuteReader()` here,  you should be able to just use `ExecuteNonQuery()` since you're not returning any data.

Comment: I realised that the ID i'm getting is not good. The ID are generated and incremented by 1 each time. But i think i'm not retrieving it properly here.

Comment: First of all confirm the ID value so you don't have the same id for all the rows as your query has a where clause for update.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DataKeyNames` property of grid view you can pass each record's primary key value, assign the same to the button of the record under `CommandArgument`. The below code is working code. You can try the same.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowCommand">
  <EmptyDataTemplate>
     No Data Found
  </EmptyDataTemplate>
  <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" CommandName="Select" ImageUrl="~/Contents/Images/classicPencil.svg" Width="20" Height="20"   Text="View" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

//Using Direct button click event

```
 protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = sender as ImageButton;
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument);
        //Your code of update data process
    }
```

//Using grid row command event.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        //Your code of update data process
    }
```